# Custom Image viewer. Simple image-gallery not shown after duplicating it, strange behavoir

Tags: angularjs

I try to develop an Image-Viewer. I want to be able to add multiple galleries to contain the Images and it should be possible to 'duplicate' a Gallery. That's where I'm stuck right now.

I can add new galleries but cannot duplicate one. When duplicating, the Gallery is duplicated in my Array but does not get visual. When adding new galleries after that, they are not shown either.

I don't understand it at all.

Some code:

```
// Controller for binding galleries to view 
app.controller('newMainCtrl',  function($scope, ImageGalleriesService) {

    $scope.galleries = ImageGalleriesService.getGalleries();

    $scope.$watch(function(){
        return ImageGalleriesService.getGalleries();
    }, function(newVal){    
        $scope.galleries = newVal;
    });

});

// Single Image controller
app.controller('imageCtrl', function($scope, ImageGalleriesService) {

    $scope.imageinit = function(value)
    {
        $scope.imageitem = value;
    };

});

// Gallery controller
app.controller('galleryCtrl', function($scope, ImageGalleriesService) {


    $scope.init = function(gallery) {
        $scope.gallery = gallery;
    };

    $scope.duplicate = function()
    {
        ImageGalleriesService.addImageGallery($scope.gallery, null, 2);
    };



});

// Service that holds all the galleries
app.service('ImageGalleriesService', function() {

    var imagegalleries = []; 

    this.getGalleries = function(){
        return imagegalleries;
    };

    this.addImageGallery = function(imagegallery){

            imagegalleries.push(imagegallery);
    };

});
```

I made a [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/xiAkjItX2Q2wi2Ud8U0X?p=preview) to Show the Problem.

Any help appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `track by $index` in your html 
 `ng-repeat="gallery_ in galleries track by $index"`

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to add the same object to `imagegalleries` (It's the same reference). An easy fix is to call `angular.copy()` when you add the new gallery:

```
this.addImageGallery = function(imagegallery){
  imagegalleries.push(angular.copy(imagegallery));
};
```

Here's the updated [Plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/i7tl4a7F57FNYLspU2zO).

Answer (score 0):

When you render the components using `ng-repeat` look at your console (F12 in chrome > console).

You're getting an error there:

```
Error: [ngRepeat:dupes] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.7/ngRepeat/dupes?p0=gallery_%20in%20galleri…22%3A0%2C%22images%22%3A%5B%5D%2C%22%24%24hashKey%22%3A%22object%3A6%22%7D
```

Read the official documentation about this error [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/ngRepeat/dupes):

> Duplicates in a repeater are not allowed. Use 'track by' expression to
>   specify unique keys. Repeater: {0}, Duplicate key: {1}, Duplicate
>   value: {2}

---

**Explaination**

Consider this code snippet:

You've 2 ng-repeat in this snippet (i.e., ng-repeat #1 and ng-repeat #2). Both ng-repeat are rendering duplicates.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
    <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.4.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.9/angular.js" data-semver="1.4.9"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
     ng-repeat #1
     <div ng-repeat="n in [42, 42, 43, 43]">
        {{n}}
      </div>
 <hr>
     ng-repeat #2
      <div ng-repeat="n in [42, 42, 43, 43] track by $index">
        {{n}}
      </div>
      
  <script>
    var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

    app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
      $scope.name = 'World';
    });

  </script>
  </body>

</html>
```

```
Error: [ngRepeat:dupes] Duplicates in a repeater are not allowed.  
Use 'track by' expression to specify unique keys.   
Repeater: n in [42, 42, 43, 43],   
Duplicate key: number:42, Duplicate value: 42
```

### And so when we use `track by` in ng-repeat #2, it works fine.

And because you've duplicates in your array, so you've to use `track by` in your `ng-repeat` to get rid of that error, like this:

```
    <section ng-repeat="gallery_ in galleries track by $index">
        <div ng-controller="galleryCtrl" ng-init="init(gallery_)" style="margin: auto" >
            <div style="width: 90%; height: 40px; margin: auto; border: 1px solid orange;" >
                <button ng-click="duplicate()">duplicate me</button>
            </div>
            <div  style="width: 90%; min-height: 150px; margin: auto; overflow-x: auto; white-space: nowrap; border: 1px solid orange;"  >  
                <div  ng-repeat="file in gallery.images"  style=" display: inline-block; background-color: white; position: relative;" >
                    <div ng-controller="imageCtrl" ng-init="imageinit(file)" >
                        <figure id="{{imageitem.id}}" ng-style="imageitem.style"  style="width: 200px; height: 200px;"> 
                        <figcaption style="color: white">
                            {{ imageitem.id }} 
                        </figcaption>
                        </figure> 
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
```